# How to add additional data in power bi when I have already connected to Analysis Services?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

All the options for for get data is blacked (Please check this image)

[image: All the options for for get data is blacked (Please check this image)]

Comment: Do you use import or directQuery? If DirectQuery then read:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/directquery-for-power-bi-datasets-and-azure-analysis-services-preview/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-composite-models

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.